# multiuser capable and search option available in app

Tags: iphone, ipad, osx-server

I need to make my app such that

1. the first screen will have the option : NEW and SEARCH. 
   2.Clicking NEW should allow the user to create a new profile, 
   3.but clicking search should allow to access one of the stored profiles by searching for the user number.

These profiles will actually be some data about the person, his name etc. and then yes/no answers to some questions.

At the moment my app works such that I can type in my name, and do the yes/no checks and I am  using plists  to save the info. this means that when the I start the app the next time the app loads with the saved info. So I have got half the task done.

Now how do I make it multi-user capable so that it has the option of creating a new file or providing a search option to access existing data?

also, I am creating the plist in application directory, using the code on apple's website, but I have no clue how to access these files directly..is it possible to access these files, if I want to show the information on a desktop? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The key phrase you want for searching Apple's docs is: [Data Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/search/?q=data%20management).

Specifically, I would recommend the [Data Management Starting Point.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_DataManagement_iPhone/)

Handling data can be as simple as writing a string or array to disk or as complex as a big Core Data data model. If you plan on writing and maintaining several Apple API apps, I strongly recommend eventually learning Core Data.